How can Notion calculate days spend depending on 2 date properties and whether or not one of them is empty?
I have 2 properties, Start Date and End Date. I want Notion to calculate the "Days spend", so from Start Date to End date or, if End Date is empty, from Start Date to today.
I tried a few things and searching on forums, but can't seem to figure it out.
The formula I used before only calculated the Days spend when End Date was not empty:
if(not empty(prop("End date")), dateBetween(prop("End date"), prop("Start date"), "days"), toNumber(""))

